# How to call a function from another kernel module in a kernel module?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I've written three kernel modules. A, B, C. 
B needs some functions from A and C also. How to achieve this. Please be code specific. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the function implementation in A, export it:

```
#include "moduleA_header.h"

int foo(void)
{
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "Hi there!\n");
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(foo);
```

Make sure that the prototype of your function is declared in a header file that you can include in module B. Also, make sure module A gets loaded before module B.

Just make sure that your include has the path right to the moduleA_header.h file.

Comment: Could you please show me the directory structure. Should these modules be in same directory (and also header file too)?

Comment: @mahesh The modules don't need to be in the same directory. All you need for that to work is to be able to include the definition of `int foo()` into the code of your module B.

Comment: How to return character arrays? While compiling it says return address of local variable.

Comment: @mahesh I am afraid your last comment is beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: So should I ask another question?

Comment: @mahesh Indeed. One StackOverflow question per question.